# Counting ideals in number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I want to understand how to generalize standard facts in number theory on rational integer ideals to more general number fields. We know that for instance 
$$\# \{k \in \mathbb{Z} \ : \ 1 \leq k \leq N\} = N.$$

For a number field $F$ with ring of integers $\mathfrak{o}$, what can be said of
$$\#\{\mathfrak{n} \subset \mathfrak{o} \ : \ 0 \leqslant \text{norm}(\mathfrak{n}) \leqslant N\} \quad ?$$

and is it straightforward from the first result?

Comment: Indeed, one should ask the question instead for ideals.

Comment: @Hurkyl, indeed my question is about ideals, I will edit the title.

Answer (score 2):

One has the general asymptotic

$$\#\{\mathfrak{n} \subset \mathfrak{o} \ : \ 0 \leqslant \text{norm}(\mathfrak{n}) \leqslant N\} = \rho N + O(N^{1 - 1/n}) $$

where $ n = [F : \mathbf Q] $ and the quantity $ \rho > 0 $ depends on the number field $ F $. (This lemma is used in the proof of the analytic class number formula.) You can find a proof (along with the full statement of the result, with the actual expression for $ \rho $) [here](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes18.pdf).